# JavaFX Anchor Constraints

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I have an FXML file which has a split pane and 2 rectangles in it.  I have both rectangles anchored properly via the FXML but from the code I am generating new rectangles but I can't seem to get the constraints on them working, I set them to the same settings as the rectangles in the FXML(constraint wise) but nothing.  I think the issue is the rectangles in the FXML are inside a Split Pane where as the ones generated from the Java code are in the Main AnchorPane.  Here is the code any ideas?

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    //GridPane root = new GridPane();
    AnchorPane root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/TestConveyorView.fxml")).getRoot();
    Box box = new Box(1);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50,50, box.getStatus().getColor());
    rect.setX(385.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(rect, 385.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(rect, 294.0);
    root.getChildren().addAll(rect);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // BackgroundImage background = new BackgroundImage(null, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing all the extra code in the main class like below.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    AnchorPane root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/TestConveyorView.fxml")).getRoot();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // BackgroundImage background = new BackgroundImage(null, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

And adding these to things to my controller

```
@FXML
AnchorPane Splitright;
Splitright.getChildren().add(rectangle);
```

As it turns out the shapes were just being thrown on top of everything not actually being placed in the proper AnchorPane, which is what I suspected was happening.